# Reload Markers google maps api with response api

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I want to add new markers to google maps api. After that, it will go to `sweetalert` and then reload page to show marker. How do I update / show marker without reload after save with `sweetalert` ?

Here's the script from response api

```
//response from json, data existing
var exist = [{"name":"mysql",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"88909090",
                  "long":"1010010"
             }}, 
             {"name":"golang",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"86080080",
                  "long":"111000"
             }}]
```

Here's the script after save new marker

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>qr/addmarker",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{
            "names":names,
            "lat":lat,
            "long":long
        },
        success: function(response){
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Success',
                text: 'Pin has been moved',
                icon: 'success',
                timer: 2000,
                showConfirmButton: false
            }).then(function() {
                //console.log("string")
                document.location.reload();
                
            });
        }
    })
```

Here's script to show marker on map

```
 for (var i = 0; i < exist.length; i++) 
 {
     var form_name = exist[i].names
     var lat = exist[i].geolocation.lat
     var long = exist[i].geolocation.long

     if(exist[i].geolocation.lat != null){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(exist[i].geolocation.lat, exist[i].geolocation.long),
                 map: map
         });
         marker.setMap(map);
     }
 }
```

Comment: use the callback in the ajax function to add a new marker and remove the `location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to create a simple function to add markers, such as:

```
const addmarker=function( map, lat, long, name ){
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        name:name,
        title:name,
        map:map
     });
}
```

( Not knowing the full code involved I added the `map` as a parameter to the function but this could be a global variable for all I know so could perhaps be omitted. )

Then you can use that function initially on page load to load the markers:

```
for( var i = 0; i < exist.length; i++ ) {
    if( exist[i].geolocation.lat != null ){
        var form_name = exist[i].names;
        var lat = exist[i].geolocation.lat;
        var long = exist[i].geolocation.long;
        
        addmarker(map, lat, long, form_name );
    }
}
```

And also in the callback within your ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>qr/addmarker",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{
        "names":names,
        "lat":lat,
        "long":long
    },
    success: function(response){
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Success',
            text: 'Pin has been moved',
            icon: 'success',
            timer: 2000,
            showConfirmButton: false
        }).then(function(){
        
            response.forEach(obj=>{
                addmarker( map, obj.geolocation.lat, obj.geolocation.long, obj.name );
            })
            
        });
    }
})
```

None of the above could be tested so there might be small errors but the idea is ok.